# Can't find someone's tweets

Tags: twitter, twitter-search

I searched tweets by advanced search but some accounts' tweets don't appear. Why?

Comment: Are you looking at all results, and not just "Top" results?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple reasons why you may not see some tweets when searching. Some possible reasons include:

- #### The user has a "protected" account

  If someone sets their Twitter profile to be protected, only their followers can view their tweets.

---

- #### You may only be viewing "Top" results

  In the Twitter web app, by default a search will return the top results. Check the other categories (*Latest*, *People*, *News*, etc.) to see different -- and possibly more relevant -- results.

  [image]

  Alternatively, use a Twitter mobile app (iOS or Android) to have the option to view all results.

---

- #### Low-quality results are hidden

Results that Twitter deems to be low quality may not be shown. To see these results, click the **Show** option next to "Search filters" and change *Quality filter on* to *Quality filter off*.

Comment: If the account has blocked the searcher, I'd expect those to not appear in a search as well.